# How to manage magento media images under the multi server enviroment

Tags: php, magento, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I am setting up Magento into multi server environment on AWS using load balancer and auto scaling and RDS and I am New on it.

There is the following things that need to share between these server.

1. **Session :** Found the solution to store it into Database.
2. **Cache :** I can use AWS Elastic Cache.
3. **Media/Product image :** I searched for it and found that, magento has a option to save the  media into the databse under the configuration setting.

I tried to set it to database and synchronized it, deleted the cache folder and then checked at front end, but still it is showing the media path(File System Path) into the product image URL. I also tried by creating new products but showing the same. I do not sure how it works.

My understanding is that, If we select database option to store the media, Then magento stores the images into the database as BLOB instead File System. And at front end it directly fetch from the database, No dependency on the file system. Am I correct on this?

If it works according to my understanding then I can store the images into the database and it will get shared between the multiple server.

Please suggest I am going on right track or not? Or any other solution to share the media between the multiple server with minimal changed into the magento will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm trying the same setup but I don't know how to do it yet.

Comment: Yes, I find it and successfully setup this environment. You just need to choose save storage media into database under the configuration and it server from that centralized place.

Comment: In my case there were certain customization that was causing the problem, In default one it works perfect,  Gud luck  :)